# Использование svg-анимации, уменьшающей непрозрачность прямоугольника при клике на прямоугольнике

Tags: html5, svg, анимация, opacity

Мне нужно изменить непрозрачность (от 1 до 0) прямоугольника при нажатии на прямоугольник.

Я использовал svg анимацию. Но я не могу изменить прозрачность прямоугольника. Если кто-нибудь знает, пожалуйста, помогите мне.

```html
<svg height="800px" width="1100px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect id="rect1" x="263" y="87.5" width="100" height="25" fill="#F67F33" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1">
     <animate
       xlink:href="#rect1"
       attributeName="opacity"
       from="1"
       to="0"
       begin="click"
       fill="freeze" />
  </rect>
</svg>
```

*Примечание переводчика:*

Этот очень простой вопрос выбран для перевода по двум причинам
 Порою долго приходится искать причину из-за которой не работает анимация и это очень простой и показательный  пример для начала обучения по анимациям SVG

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54322097/7394871

Answer (score 2):

У вас нет продолжительности анимации. Также, если `animate` является дочерним элементом svg элемента, оно не требует `xlink:href`.

```html
<svg height="800px" width="1100px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect x="263" y="87.5" width="100" height="25" fill="#F67F33" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1">
     <animate
       attributeName="opacity"
       from="1"
       to="0"
       dur="3s"
       begin="click"
       fill="freeze" />
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы анимация была мгновенной, вы можете использовать `set`

```html
<svg height="800px" width="1100px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect x="263" y="87.5" width="100" height="25" fill="#F67F33" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1">
     <set
       attributeName="opacity"
       to="0"
       begin="click"
       fill="freeze" />
  </rect>
</svg>
```